# How pass the variable in to array JS

Tags: javascript

The problem is simple. When I take the variable into the array it doesn't work. When I write the variable into inputs it works. How can I pass the variable into the array?

```
var testW = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
var testQ = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteObjectbyJS");

var testlength = testW.length;

if(testW[testlength].value == ""){
    testQ[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: JavaScript arrays are 0-based indexed. If your array has no items in it, the length of the array is 0 (`testlength`). When your code tries to access the data at index 0 of the array, it finds there's nothing there which results in the array returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in JS start indexing from `0` to `SIZE-1` so your code is wrong here:

```
if(testW[testlength-1].value == ""){
    testQ[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

I don't know if this solve your problem completly but this is an error for sure

Answer (score 0):

`testW[testlength]` should be `testW[testlength-1]`

Answer (score 0):

testlength is length of the list. When you trying to access testW[testlength] you actually access non existing element after the last element because elements indexes are between 0 and testlength-1.